# this error occurs when installing cisco packet tracer how can i solve it?

Tags: archive, cisco

i was trying to install cisco packet tracer in my ubuntu laptop but every time i try to install this software i get this message below:
E: The package packettracer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
And its blocks all the installation of other programs like jdk so i can't install any program

Comment: No information about the Ubunu version you use, no information where you got that package, how do you think people will be able to help you? As far as I see you use 22.04 and cisco provides a package for 20.04 but not for 22.04, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: THANK YOU AND SORRY FOR NOT GIVE FULL INFORMATION